# Check the uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{x} \exp(\frac{-n^2}{x})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{x} \exp{\frac{-n^2}{x}}$$
where $ 0 < x < \infty$

While $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} (a_n)^{1/n} = 0$$ The sum would converge. But how to check uniform convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$. I will prove it showing that Cauchy's uniform criterion is not satisfied. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{align}
\sup_{x>0}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{n^2}{x}e^{-n^2/x}&\ge\sup_{x>0}\,(n+1)\,\frac{n^2}{x}e^{-4n^2/x}\\
&\ge(n+1)\,\sup_{z>0}z\,e^{-4z}\\
&\ge\frac{n+1}{4\,e}.
\end{align}$$
Thr convergence is uniform on any interval $[a,\infty)$, $a>0$.

Comment: Perhaps simpler: $f_n(n^2) = e^{-1}$ for $f_n(x) = \frac{n^2}{x} e^{-n^2/x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ verifying $B>A>0$, consider $x \in [A,B]$. Using $$e^{-n^2/x}\leq e^{-n^2/B}$$ implying $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2e^{-n^2/x}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2e^{-n^2/B} $$ gives normal convergence of your series on each compact set $[A,B]$ and thus you have uniform convergence on any $[A,+\infty).$

Comment: I've never seen that implication before....I just did a search, and all the things I saw were related but not identical and seemed to indicate the opposite in the related case.   Can you point me to where convergence on every compact subset implies uniform convergence on the open set?

Comment: @Alan For example see: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Normal_convergence

Comment: Confirming @Alan's observation, $x^n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on every interval $[0,\delta]$ with $\delta < 1$ but does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Edited. Thank you: Daniel Fischer, RRL, Alan and Julien Aguirre.